# How could I get public array from JavaScript?

Tags: solidity, ether

I have an array in smart contract:

```
contract SuperContract {
    uint[] public SuperArrayForExample;

    function addItemToArray(uint item) payable {
       SuperArrayForExample.push(item);
    }
}
```

I try to get this array from JavaScript:

```js
contract['SuperArrayForExample'](uint256).call().then(response => {
   console.log(response); // I would like to see my array here
});
```

I would like to see my array here but I get this error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) class org.tron.common.runtime.vm.program.Program$IllegalOperationException : Invalid operation code: opCode[fe];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The automatic getter that is generated will return only one element of your array and requires an input which will be the index of the element. You need to explicitly write your own getter function to get your array.

Comment: Thanks! May be do you know some methods to get array length ?

Comment: Both in solidity and Web3 you can use the '.length' operation to find the length.
For example SuperArrayForExample.length

Answer (score 0):

came late, but I solved it by simply repeatedly calling the contract to get the index until I got an error, usually arrays in solidity are quite small so this isn't such a bad thing performance-wise, would be smart to cache it if it wouldn't update often, it uses ethersjs but I guess with web3js it wouldn't be too different.

It is however better to expose a function that returns the length from the contract, but if you have no control over the contract or it's already deployed, this works:

```
const solidityPublicArrayToJsArray = async<T = any>(contract: Contract, arrayName: string) => {
  let err: Error| undefined = undefined;
  let array: T[] = [];
  while (err === undefined) {
    try {
      const item = await contract[arrayName](array.length) as T;
      array.push(item);
    } catch (e) {
      err = e as Error;
    }
  }
  return array;
}
```

The error message would be "Transaction reverted without a reason string" if you care about that...